# When is it more appropriate to use a pthread barrier instead of a condition wait and broadcast?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am coding a telemetry system in C++ and have been having some difficulty syncing certain threads with the standard pthread_cond_timedwait and pthread_cond_broadcast.

The problem was that I needed some way for the function that was doing the broadcasting to know if another thread acted on the broadcast.

After some hearty searching I decided I might try using a barrier for the two threads instead.  However, I still wanted the timeout functionality of the pthread_cond_timedwait.

Here is basically what I came up with: (However it feels excessive)

**Listen Function:** Checks for a period of milliseconds to see if an event is currently being triggered.

```
bool listen(uint8_t eventID, int timeout)
{  
    int waitCount = 0;  
    while(waitCount <= timeout)
    {  
        globalEventID = eventID;
        if(getUpdateFlag(eventID) == true)
        {
            pthread_barrier_wait(&barEvent);
            return true;
        }
        threadSleep(); //blocks for 1 millisecond
        ++waitCount;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Trigger Function:** Triggers an event for a period of milliseconds by setting an update flag for the triggering period

```
bool trigger(uint8_t eventID, int timeout)
    int waitCount = 0;  
    while(waitCount <= timeout)
    {  
        setUpdateFlag(eventID, true); //Sets the update flag to true
        if(globalEventID == eventID)
        {
            pthread_barrier_wait(&barEvent);
            return true;
        }
        threadSleep(); //blocks for 1 millisecond
        ++waitCount;
    }
    setUpdateFlag(eventID, false);
    return false;
}
```

My questions: Is another way to share information with the broadcaster, or are barriers really the only efficient way? Also, is there another way of getting timeout functionality with barriers?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: it's a shame that `pthread_cond_t` doesn't have a method equivalent to the `cv_has_waiters()` of BSD/Solaris, http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/cv_has_waiters.9.html - that'd be the thing you need.

Comment: That said, of course the information someone was waiting for the condvar doesn't guarantee said waiter actually "acted" in a specific way. That depends on the detailed design of your code.

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to let thread1 know that the message it is waiting for has been parsed and stored in a global list by thread2, and that thread2 can continue parsing and storing because thread1 will now copy that message from the list ensuring that thread2 can overwrite that message with a new version and not disrupt the operations of thread1.

Comment: Use a producer-consumer queue for the messages, one message per object, so that the thread1 and thread2 can never operate on the same message.  No global, no copy, no hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your described problem:

> Specifically, I am trying to let thread1 know that the message it is
>   waiting for has been parsed and stored in a global list by thread2,
>   and that thread2 can continue parsing and storing because thread1 will
>   now copy that message from the list ensuring that thread2 can
>   overwrite that message with a new version and not disrupt the
>   operations of thread1.

It sounds like your problem can be solved by having both threads alternately wait on the condition variable.  Eg. in  thread 1:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (!message_present)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
copy_message();
message_present = 0;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

process_message();
```

and in thread 2:

```
parse_message();

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (message_present)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
store_message();
message_present = 1;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```